# Splitting a dataframe into two parts based on conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes. The first one gives me information about how long someone took to resolve some task. The second dataframe gives information about the user who took a course and completed it at some time.

For example

```
d1 = {'resolved_by': ['mtt', 'mtt', 'mtt', 'maa', 'maa'],
     'resolved_date': ['2021-05-10', '2021-05-18', '2021-05-10', '2021-05-01', '2021-05-02'],
    'total_time_spent':[17, 5, 4, 10, 8],
}

df_work = pd.DataFrame(data=d1)
```

and

```
d2 = {'alias':['mtt', 'mtt', 'mtt', 'maa', 'maa'],
    'course': ['excel class', 'IT training', 'finance class', 'IT training', 'excel class'],
    'completion_date':['2021-05-12', '2021-05-16', '2021-05-19', '2021-05-02', '2021-05-03']
}

df_course = pd.DataFrame(data=d2)
```

The real dataframes are much larger than this. What I am trying to do is split the data into two different dataframes based on when that user took a particular course. What I want is if the user `mtt` took `excel_class` then I would grab that date `2021-05-12` and split the `df_work` into two dataframes one for the work completed prior to the course and one for the work done after that course was completed. i.e.,

```
d3 = {'resolved_by':['mtt','mtt'],
     'resolved_date':['2021-05-10', '2021-05-10'],
     'total_time_spent':[17, 4]}

df_work_split1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d3)
```

and

```
d4 = {'resolved_by':['mtt'],
      'resolved_date':['2021-05-18'],
      'total_time_spent':[5]}

df_work_split2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d4)
```

What I tried was this

```
for x in df_work['resolved_by']:
    if x in df_course['alias'].tolist():
        df_split1 = df_work[df_work['resolved_by'] < df_course['completion_date'].iloc[0]]
        df_split2 = df_work[df_work['resolved_by'] >= df_course['completion_date'].iloc[0]]
```

But that did not work, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use the `groupby` method to split `df_work` by aliases.
2. Extract "excel date" for this alias from `df_course`
3. Split `df_work` according to that date.

```
for alias, df_alias in df_work.groupby('resolved_by'):
    completion_date = df_course.loc[
        (df_course['alias']==alias) & (df_course['course']=='excel class'),
        'completion_date'
    ]
    if not len(completion_date):
        # skip if no excel class
        continue
    df_prior = df_alias.loc[df_alias['resolved_date']<completion_date.item()]
    df_after = df_alias.loc[df_alias['resolved_date']>=completion_date.item()]
```

This gives two dataframes for every alias that completed an excel course. If you want to use all of them, you have to merge them into a list inside the loop.

EDIT:

The following should do the trick for the update of the desired functionality.

```
def split_function(df_work, df_course, alias, course):
    
    df_alias = df_work.loc[df_work['resolved_by']==alias]
    completion_date = df_course.loc[
            (df_course['alias']==alias) & (df_course['course']==course),
            'completion_date'
        ]
    if not len(completion_date):
        # skip if no excel class
        return
    df_prior = df_alias.loc[df_alias['resolved_date']<completion_date.item()]
    df_after = df_alias.loc[df_alias['resolved_date']>completion_date.item()]
    return df_prior, df_after

        
df_prior, df_after = split_function(df_work, df_course, 'mtt', 'excel class')
```

Comment: Yes, I would need this to be adapted to all courses, besides just `excel_class`. What do you mean by merge them into list?

Comment: @justanewb This should be done using a function. See my edit.